# Strange error while adding a feature to my little game (0xC0000005)

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, heap-memory

### Hello everyone,

I decided some time ago to write my own version of Minesweepers as some practice and I did it. The game ran perfectly, but after deciding to add a "Choose difficulty" option the window freezes and I get an error message, saying that the program does not respond. Also the line **0xC0000005** appeares. I have tryed many, many things: moving code from **main()** to a seperate function(**now all in int playGame()**), allocating some more memory in the heap, even creating a seperate .c file to store some piece of the code, but nothing worked sofar. I came back to the code after a few weeks, but I still have no clue why it is happening.
Can anyone help me with this? I hope my code is not hard to read. I added some comments explaining what is what. I am still new to C.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include "difLvl.c"

    int displayFiled(char **field); //prints out the map of the field
    int combine(char answer, int answer1); //combines user input and field       numeration
    int Randomizer(int **mineArray); //generates random mine map
    int difficulty();
    int playGame();

    int main(){

        int playGame();

        playGame();

        system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}

int Randomizer(int **mineArray){

    int difficulty();
    int i, j;
    srand(time(NULL));
    int mines;
    int placeMine;
    int totalMines;
    //int difLvl=2;
    int difLvl=difficulty();

    for(i=0, totalMines=0; i<10; i++){
        for(j=0, mines=0; j<10 && mines<difLvl; j++){
            placeMine= rand() % 2;
            mineArray[i][j] = placeMine;
            if(placeMine==1){
                ++mines;
            };
        };
        totalMines+=mines;
    };

    return totalMines;
}

int displayFiled(char **field){

    int i, j;

    printf("    A B C D E F G H I J\n");
    printf("   --------------------\n");
    for (i=0; i<10; i++){
            if (i==9){
                printf("%d |", i+1);
            }else{
                printf("%d  |", i+1);
            };
        for (j=0; j<10; j++){
            printf("%c ", field[i][j]);
            if (j==9){
                printf("\n");
                };
        };
    };
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

int playGame(){

    int displayFiled(char **field);
    int combine(char answer, int answer1);
    int Randomizer(int ** mineArray);
    char Y_char; //column as character (a, b, c etc.)
    int X; //row 
    int Y; //Y_char converted to a number 
    int **mineArray; //stores the map of mines
    char **fieldDisplay; //prints out the map of the field
    int i, j; //counters
    int life=1;
    int movePl=0; //no dying on the first move
    int globalMines; //number of mines placed
    int openedFields=0; //counts the number of fields opened
    //int difLvl;
    //int difficulty();

    //difLvl= difficulty();

    /*disabled the trhee lines above while I was trying some solutions*/
    /*int difficulty() is now called from int Randomizer()*/

    system("cls");

    /*Allocates memory to mineArray*/
    mineArray= (int*)calloc(10, sizeof(int));
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        mineArray[i] = calloc(10, sizeof(int));
    };


    /*Allocates memory to fieldDisplay*/
    fieldDisplay= (int*)calloc(10, sizeof(int));
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        fieldDisplay[i] = calloc(10, sizeof(int));
    };

    /*default look of fields with ?*/
    for (i=0; i<10; i++){
        for (j=0; j<10; j++){
            fieldDisplay[i][j]='?';
        };
    };

    globalMines= Randomizer(mineArray);

    while(life==1 && openedFields<(100-globalMines)){

        /*for checking purposes only*/
        /*for (i=0; i<10; i++){
            for (j=0; j<10; j++){
                printf("%d ", mineArray[i][j]);
            if (j==9){
                printf("\n");
                };
            };
        };*/

        //printf("\nDifficulty level %d\n", difLvl);
        printf("Total number of mines is %d\n\n", globalMines);
        printf("\tMove nr. %d\n\n", movePl+1);
        displayFiled(fieldDisplay);

        printf("Which field do You want to activate?\nType first the letter, space and then the number (A 1, B 10 etc.)\n");
        scanf("%c %d", &Y_char, &X);
        if (Y_char >= 'A' && Y_char <= 'Z'){
            Y = Y_char - 'A';
        }else if(Y_char >= 'a' && Y_char <= 'z'){
            Y = Y_char - 'a';
        };

        /*checks if a field is a mine*/
        /*X-1 because the player chooses from 1 to 10*/
        if (mineArray[X-1][Y]==0 && fieldDisplay[X-1][Y]=='?'){
            movePl++;
            fieldDisplay[X-1][Y]='0';
            openedFields=openedFields+1;

OPEN :      if (((X-2)<10) && ((X-2)>=0)){
                if (mineArray[X-2][Y]==0 && fieldDisplay[X-2][Y]=='?'){
                    fieldDisplay[X-2][Y]='0';
                    openedFields=openedFields+1;
                };
            };

            if ((X<10) && (X>=0)){
                if (mineArray[X][Y]==0 && fieldDisplay[X][Y]=='?'){
                    fieldDisplay[X][Y]='0';
                    openedFields=openedFields+1;
                };
            };

            if (((Y+1)<10) && ((Y+1)>=0)){
                if (mineArray[X-1][Y+1]==0 && fieldDisplay[X-1][Y+1]=='?'){
                    fieldDisplay[X-1][Y+1]='0';
                    openedFields=openedFields+1;
                };
            };

            if (((Y-1)<10) && ((Y-1)>=0)){
                if (mineArray[X-1][Y-1]==0 && fieldDisplay[X-1][Y-1]=='?'){
                    fieldDisplay[X-1][Y-1]='0';
                    openedFields=openedFields+1;
                };
            };

            system("cls"); //clears console screen
        }else if (mineArray[X-1][Y]==0 && fieldDisplay[X-1][Y]=='0'){
            system("cls");
            printf("You can't choose an already opened field!\n\n");
        }else if(mineArray[X-1][Y]==1 && movePl==0){
        /*only activates on the first turn if players hits mine*/
            movePl++;
            mineArray[X-1][Y]= 0;
            fieldDisplay[X-1][Y]='0';
            globalMines=globalMines-1;
            goto OPEN;
            system("cls");
        }else{
            system("cls");
            printf("YOU DIED ! YOU DIED ! YOU DIED !\n\n");
            printf("Moves successfully made: %d\n\n", movePl-1);
            fieldDisplay[X-1][Y]='1';
            displayFiled(fieldDisplay);
            --life;
        };
    };

    if(openedFields==(100-globalMines)){
        printf("Congratulations! You won the game!\n\n");
        displayFiled(fieldDisplay);
    };

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        free(mineArray[i]);
    };
    free(mineArray);

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        free(fieldDisplay[i]);
    };
    free(fieldDisplay);



    return 0;

}
```

The difLvl.c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int difficulty(){

    int difLvl;

    while(1){
        printf("Please choose a difficulty level:\n");
        printf("Easy-1\nNormal-2\nNightmare-3\n");
        printf("Your answer: ");
        scanf(" %d", &difLvl);
        if(difLvl>=1 && difLvl<=3){
            break;
        }else{
            system("cls");
            continue;
        };
    };
    system("cls");
    return difLvl;
}
```

I created it, because I thought that maybe **main()** had too many code in it and that maybe that was why the difficulty option wasnt working right.

EDIT
After the user is promped to enter the difficulty level, the mine map is created, but after choosing a filed, the program crashes.

**SOLVED**
scanf("%c %d", &Y_char, &X);
changed to
scanf(" %c %d", &Y_char, &X);

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The desired behavior would be not to crash. The error is 0xC0000005. I read online that it is a memory violation, but there shouldnt be any. The space isn't any problem. I just removed it, and the output is the same.

Comment: @MilanTodorovic The problem isn't the desired behavior; we all understand that you don't want your program to crash. The problem is the wall of code that you have posted. Please try to distill it down to "the shortest code necessary to reproduce" the error.

Comment: `mineArray= (int*)calloc(10, sizeof(int));` should be `mineArray= calloc(10, sizeof(int *));`. Same goes for `fieldDisplay` a few lines later. This may be a problem on 64-bit machines that have 8 byte pointers, but 4 byte ints.

Comment: @user3386109 just tryed it, but it doesn't help :/

Comment: Yep, that's why I didn't post it as an answer. It's something that needed to be fixed, but it was unlikely to fix everything.

Comment: @user3386109 thanks! i read many times and even saw it in tutorials that people use that type cast for portability between C and C++ or something. I just wanted to make it a habbit, so I wont have to worry in a few years.

Comment: for a 'proper' project,  strongly suggest a new file: difLvl.h that contains (at least) the prototype for Difficulty().  This new header file needs to be included in both the *.c files.   Then the gcc link command needs to reference both *.o files   As it is, moving some of the code to a separate file is not helping, as the contents of that file are being #included into the main file

Comment: the first line after main(), 'int playgame();' needs to be eliminated.  The prototype for the playgame() function is already listed just before the main() function..  Actually, ALL the function prototypes, except those just before main() need to be eliminated.  They are not needed and just clutter the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you don't allocate your two-dimensional fields correctly. The "outer" field must hold `int *`, not just `int`:

```
mineArray = calloc(10, sizeof(*mineArray));
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    mineArray[i] = calloc(10, sizeof(*mineArray[i]));
}
```

Another potential source of the segmentation fault is that `Y` might end up uninitialised and therefore with a garbage value. The cause is the `scanf`:

```
scanf("%c %d", &Y_char, &X);
```

Most `scanf` formats skip white space before the conversion, but `%c` doesn't. It is very likely that you read the newline character as the char for `%c` when you expect to read a letter. Because the new-line character is white space, you can hot-fix the by placing a space before the `%c`?  format:

```
scanf(" %c %d", &Y_char, &X);
```

(I say hot-fix, because it isn't a good solution. `scanf` doesn't treat new-line characters specially; they are just space. A better solution might be to read a line first with `fgets` and then scan that with `sscanf`. At least you can treat each line as frash input. (And your input really should ensure that bad input is ignored.)

Lastly, it is strange that you include a `*.c` file. If you want to spread ypur project over various files, which is basically a good idea, you should write a header file for each `*.c`, which has the file's interface. Include the header files in other `*.c` files; compile the `*.c` files into objects separately and then link them. This process is usually controlled by Makefiles or Projects.

Comment: those part of the code worked before without any issue. The problem startted appearing after I added the int difficulty(). It causes the problem, but I dont know why it would :/
I am still not familiar with big projects and speeating through out many *.c files. I did this one because I thought the reason of the error might be because of too much code in one file, if that is even possible.

Comment: The uninitialised value `Y` is on the stack. It really contains garbage. The stack grows and shrinks and that garbage value was a sensible value in a previously called function. Calling another function before can change the garbage value. Maybe it was, say, 0 before and now is a large value. But it's still garbage. Using uninitialised values is undefined behaviour, which is not a guarantee to crach. It's just an unreliable condition, where anything can happen.

Comment: *"too much code in one file"* would be millions of lines of code. In addition to the `scanf` fix, you should really range check both `X` and `Y` after the user input.  For example, consider what happens if the user types `@ 55`. When writing code that gets user input, you should always assume that the user input will be wrong in the most horrible way, and the code should protect itself from that.